# how to do this with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

In this scnerio, `ExistID(2,10)`

`2` to `10` is `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` must exist control in myTable.
If somebody exists in ID column, return false. How to this with linq? I'm newbie in linq.

MyTable :

```
    ID    
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

-

```
    myDBDataContext db;

    public bool ExistID(int startId, int endId)
    {
     //return db.MyTables...
    }
```

Comment: Why does it return an `int`? Your text implies it want to return a yes/no answer (so a `bool`).

Comment: I wrongly writed it. Thanks.

Comment: "If somebody exists in ID Column" - You want this method to return true if all values in the range exist in ID column, or if at least one value is missing?

Comment: So your actual question, you want to check if ALL numbers from startId to endId exists in the MyTable.ID values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public bool ExistID(int startId, int endId)
{
     return db.MyTables.Any(x => x.ID >= startId && x.ID <= endId);
}
```

This method returns `true` if some value from `startId` to `endId` exists in table.